# Does this sound natural to native speakers?

Tags: american-english

I hit the nail on the head when I had to decide to build this project from scratch.

Comment: Seems like a non-sequitur to me.

Comment: What is your problem with it? Grammar, mixed metaphor, or what?

Comment: I am just wondering about its general usage.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound right because the phrase 'hit the nail on the head' implicitly suggests that one has chosen the right option amongst a choice of options. But in your sentence there isn't any sense of there being a search for options. In other words, some contextual information is missingand this might require additional sentences.

Although classically, the unit of sense is the sentence, in some/many cases the sense is carroed across several sentences.

Plus stylistically speaking, the sentence seems rather cliched. After all, you've used two cliches in one sentence: "hitting the nail on the head" and "from scratch".

Comment: Hi, Mozibur. Thank you for your answer. That makes much sense. 
What about this sentence?
"I hit the nail on the head with my idea of changing this project from A to B". 
Does this make more sense?